# Difficulty in finding PhoneGap tutorial for windows environment

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, windows-7

I have searched several times to find a PhoneGap tutorial which is based on Windows environment but whichever tutorial I'm getting is based on Mac OS. I Have just started using PhoneGap for Android application development to use it as a plug-in for a barcode scanner app. I am working on Windows 7 environment and using Eclipse. So, I need a tutorial which is based on Windows as I am a beginner. Any help would be appreciated.

I've checked http://www.vsnomad.com/ which is suggested by @Craig, just now. But unfortunately, first of all it is a trial basis extension and second, a sign up is required. So, is there any alternative to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Visual Studio then I would recommend looking at www.vsnomad.com which will greatly simplify PhoneGap development on Windows.

Comment: Thank you. I've checked it just now. But unfortunately, first of all it is a trial basis extension and second, a sign up is required. So, is there any alternative to this?

Answer (score 5):

I'm working on windows server 2008, I used these couple of tutorials (it doesn't matter that much which environment you are using as long as you use eclipse).

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-eclipse-for-android.html

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/phonegap/creating-an-android-hello-world-application-with-phonegap/

Comment: Thanks...I already checked the 1st link you provided...but I haven't, the 2nd one...thanks anyway.